# Using WordPress WP_Query for Custom Queries using C#

Tags: c#, php, api, wordpress

Is there any way that you can leverage the wp_query api for custom queries to Wordpress. We are primarily a .NET house, but th emarketing team uses wordpress. We would like to leverage the API Wordpress has to get the posts and place them in our intranet. I have been able to successfully utilize the XML-RPC standard API, but it is not getting everything we need and is quite limited.

I found plenty out there on C# to php script with ONE function and Phalanger, but what I need is to be able to

1.) Access the query.php file that already exists without altering the files
2.) Access the functions in the file via C# on a per function basis as there are many functons in this file. I have found the lots of code on how to access functions using GET and POST, but that seems to only work if you have a single function within the file being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to just dump the WP content into your intranet, I'd just grab the SQL and do what you want with it, if not, and you want to access the WP posts/pages data on an ongoing basis, I would suggest a REST api.

You can use this plugin, and just query the whole data set with a CURL request, which will return some JSON you can do whatever you want with.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

Comment: Thank you @ Nick... I will look into the JSON method. Grabbing the SQL was thought about, but not an option as this data will be retrieved on the fly into the intranet. They aren't going to want to wait for some nightly push of the database for new stuff to appear. I have some experience with CURL in php and C#, so I may go this route. I'll update with my findings

Comment: Cool, best of luck. There may be another root, which would to be to connect directly to the WordPress MySQL DB with C# or your app, but this would mean creating your own API in your language of choice.